# Accessing html.tpl.php variables from outside

Tags: theming

The Drupal 7 has it's default html.tpl.php looking similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I access those variables ($styles, $scripts, etc.) from outside the html.tpl.php? (suppose from page.tpl.php)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer to your question - you can populate the variables you need by emulating the same functions that the processing function for html.tpl.php uses to render the page:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7

```
function template_process_html(&$variables) {
  // Render page_top and page_bottom into top level variables.
  $variables['page_top'] = drupal_render($variables['page']['page_top']);
  $variables['page_bottom'] = drupal_render($variables['page']['page_bottom']);
  // Place the rendered HTML for the page body into a top level variable.
  $variables['page']              = $variables['page']['#children'];
  $variables['page_bottom'] .= drupal_get_js('footer');

  $variables['head']    = drupal_get_html_head();
  $variables['css']     = drupal_add_css();
  $variables['styles']  = drupal_get_css();
  $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
}
```

So to access the styles variable, you would just need to call the same function the template engine is using:

```
$mystyles = drupal_get_css();
```

However - just to check, these values are already on your page because the html.tpl file is a wrapper for page.tpl.php. Sure you want to print it twice?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because we maintain several drupal installations (some of them are drupal 6, which does not have the html.tpl.php) and we use the same theme across them (everything is defined in page.tpl.php). So for compatibility, I am trying to create a "dummy" html.tpl.php. However, for drupal 7 I still need access to those variables to use them inside our page.tpl.php. Thank You!